# Here maps is not working

Tags: android, here-api

I want to implement **[HERE Maps](https://www.here.com/)** in my App. I just started to implement a sample app that just show **HERE Maps**.

### My code:

```
// map embedded in the map fragment
private Map map = null;

// map fragment embedded in this activity
private MapFragment mapFragment = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_here_maps);

    // Search for the map fragment to finish setup by calling init().
    mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.mapfragment);

      /*com.here.android.mpa.common.MapSettings.setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath(
                "/sdcard/foo/myservice"
                , "com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService");*/

    mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(
                OnEngineInitListener.Error error) {
            if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {
                // retrieve a reference of the map from the map fragment
                map = mapFragment.getMap();
                // Set the map center to the Vancouver region (no animation)
                map.setCenter(
                        new GeoCoordinate(49.196261, -123.004773, 0.0),
                        Map.Animation.NONE);
                // Set the zoom level to the average between min and max
                map.setZoomLevel((map.getMaxZoomLevel() + map
                        .getMinZoomLevel()) / 2);
            } else {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

But unfortunately it's not working.

### Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Map Fragment embedded with the map object -->

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### Logcat:

```
08-13 13:02:48.206: W/System.err(9062): org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected end of document
08-13 13:02:48.226: W/System.err(9062):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:125)
08-13 13:02:48.226: W/System.err(9062):     at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:107)
08-13 13:02:48.226: W/System.err(9062):     at com.nokia.maps.fh.a(XmlToDocParser.java:24)
08-13 13:02:48.226: W/System.err(9062):     at com.nokia.maps.ResourceManager.a(ResourceManager.java:212)
08-13 13:02:48.226: W/System.err(9062):     at com.nokia.maps.ResourceManager.a(ResourceManager.java:138)
08-13 13:02:48.226: W/System.err(9062):     at com.nokia.maps.as.<init>(GLConfigHelper.java:38)
08-13 13:02:48.226: W/System.err(9062):     at com.nokia.maps.y.a(BaseTextureView.java:61)
08-13 13:02:48.226: W/System.err(9062):     at com.nokia.maps.y.<init>(BaseTextureView.java:54)
08-13 13:02:48.226: W/System.err(9062):     at com.nokia.maps.bx.<init>(MapTextureView.java:36)
08-13 13:02:48.226: W/System.err(9062):     at com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapView.a(MapView.java:320)
08-13 13:02:48.231: W/System.err(9062):     at com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:169)
08-13 13:02:48.231: W/System.err(9062):     at com.nokia.maps.bk.a(MapFragmentImpl.java:143)
08-13 13:02:48.231: W/System.err(9062):     at com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:147)
08-13 13:02:48.231: W/System.err(9062):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1699)
08-13 13:02:48.231: W/System.err(9062):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:879)
08-13 13:02:48.231: W/System.err(9062):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1053)
08-13 13:02:48.231: W/System.err(9062):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1155)
08-13 13:02:48.231: W/System.err(9062):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4966)
08-13 13:02:48.231: W/System.err(9062):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
08-13 13:02:48.231: W/System.err(9062):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
08-13 13:02:48.231: W/System.err(9062):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
08-13 13:02:48.231: W/System.err(9062):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
08-13 13:02:48.231: W/System.err(9062):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
08-13 13:02:48.231: W/System.err(9062):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
08-13 13:02:48.231: W/System.err(9062):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
08-13 13:02:48.231: W/System.err(9062):     at com.globetech.gticket.activity.zonar.HereMapsActivity.onCreate(HereMapsActivity.java:30)
08-13 13:02:48.231: W/System.err(9062):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
08-13 13:02:48.231: W/System.err(9062):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
08-13 13:02:48.231: W/System.err(9062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
08-13 13:02:48.231: W/System.err(9062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
08-13 13:02:48.231: W/System.err(9062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
08-13 13:02:48.231: W/System.err(9062):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
08-13 13:02:48.236: W/System.err(9062):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-13 13:02:48.236: W/System.err(9062):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
08-13 13:02:48.236: W/System.err(9062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419).android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
```

I already add in `manifest.xml`

```
 <!-- Here Maps Authenticate -->

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.here.android.maps.appid"
        android:value="AppId" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.here.android.maps.apptoken"
        android:value="Apptoken" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.here.android.maps.license.key"
        android:value="LIC" />
```

But still it's not working. Please some budy give me some hint.

As i refer https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android/topics/app-extended.html

Comment: Looks like internal failure of the Here Maps component, the crash seems to be triggered by setContentView when MapView initializes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So finally it's working after 5 hours.

I just added `armeabi-v7a` folder from `HERE-sdk/libs` to my `Eclipse` Project `libs`.

### OutPut:

[image]

Comment: the HERE maps SDK has a native component and thus requires the native libraries be included in the apk as you discovered. Frustrating that you had to figure this out the hard way, there should be an instructive failure message in this case.

Comment: Ya you're right. But I never worked on native before so I didn't know more about it. And Also HERE maps do not provide all the information correctly. So its very difficult to worked around.

Comment: Android Studio users: make sure to place the armeabi-v7a folder under src/main/jniLibs and not together with HERE-sdk.jar under app/libs.