# How to embed google turn by turn navigation in my app?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am building an android app that helps the user navigate between two points. This is the link to the [doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation). This is the exact functionality that I want to provide to the user, however I want the navigation to take place in my app rather than by launching the intent in this way

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Taronga+Zoo,+Sydney+Australia");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

I have embedded google map in my app but cannot think of how to implement this navigation. Can somebody guide me or provide any hints or tutorial regarding the same? Thanks in advance !!

Comment: "however I want the navigation to take place in my app" -- have you arranged to license turn-by-turn navigation data from somebody? Have you read the terms of service for using Maps V2, which (last I checked) specifically bar developers from using Maps V2 from offering real-time turn-by-turn navigation?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, didn't know that !! Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible in `Google Maps V2 API`. Better to used **HERE Maps** for that. I recently implemented in my app and it's awesome.

Reference go to https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/map-guidance.html

Also go to [Here maps is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982280/here-maps-is-not-working/31985811#31985811)

### Looks like:

[image]

Comment: M D, thanks for the reply. I just want to ask one thing before implementing it. Is it as good as google maps or does it have any serious limitations or inferiority compared to google maps? Thanks !!

Comment: @varunkr There is no limitation.It's totally free but if you want to implement some extra feature then wlli ready for pay.

Answer (score 3):

the question is old but for reference i put the answer because i  needed the answer and found it on google website, now as 2018 google added this feature but not for everyone you need to contact them personally 
this is google explanations about this subject and the contract page to contact them about  your request https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/ridesharing/